# SharePoint SPFx extension for full width on a teams site

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an SPFx extension I created with the purpose of displaying sections with the full-width view for a teams site. My extension allows me to override any of the elements on the page. I now only need to write the css which allows me to do this, however I am having issues finding the exact classes I need to override. My question is:

**Which class do I need to edit in order to make sections appear across 100% of the screen?**

Comment: You might able to do it by overriding the classes & applying custom CSS. However, DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates. Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SharePoint framework (SPFx) web parts with full-width column or single part app pages in SharePoint Online.

Check these Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Use web parts with the full-width column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column)
2. [Using single part app pages in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages?)

---

You might able to achieve your requirements by inspecting DOM elements to get the required classes and overriding the classes with custom CSS.

However, such DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are not recommended by Microsoft and some of your customizations may break in future if Microsoft changes HTML element classes in new SharePoint release updates in future.

Check related thread: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

Answer (score 0):

On a Communication Sharepoint Site , there is no problem viewing your pages in full width .

It's a bit more tricky on a Teams Site .
For me , this worked :

- Edit the .scss file under project_name/src/webparts/webpart_name :

```css
:global {
      #workbenchPageContent,.CanvasComponent.LCS .CanvasZone {
        min-width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
```

- Include that .scss file in main react file
- Enable full-bleed support in your config

  - in your **manifest.json** file under **/src/webparts/webpart_name** , add these lines:

    "supportedHosts": ["SharePointWebPart", "TeamsPersonalApp", "TeamsTab",
    "SharePointFullPage"],
    "supportsFullBleed": true,